# How can I draw a outer contour for binary image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, contour

I have an image which has 3 classes which are labelled {2,3,4} as the left figure in first row.

For each class, I want to draw a contour  which is outer contour of the class as the image in second row. I tried to used the Matlab code below but it shows overlap contour. How can I achieve the expected result? 
Thank you all

```
Img=ones(128,128);
Img(20:end-20,20:end-20)=2;
Img(30:end-30,30:end-30)=3;
Img(45:end-45,45:end-45)=4;
Img(50:end-65,68:end-48)=2; %% Add one more rectangular
Img(68:end-48,50:end-65)=3; %% Add one more rectangular

subplot(121);imagesc(Img);colormap(gray);hold on; axis off;axis equal;
subplot(122);imagesc(Img);colormap(gray);hold on; axis off;axis equal;
[c2,h2] = contour(Img==2,[0 1],'r','LineWidth',2);
[c3,h3] = contour(Img==3,[0 1],'g','LineWidth',2);
[c4,h4] = contour(Img==4,[0 1],'b','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain your expected result, you have to use [bwlabel](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to label connected components. Then, for each component, we will draw a single contour by using imfill to [fill](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) a hole in the component. This way will guarantee that you will draw a outer contour for each component. Using for to draw all possible component of a class. This is the code

```
Img=ones(128,128);
Img(20:end-20,20:end-20)=2;
Img(30:end-30,30:end-30)=3;
Img(45:end-45,45:end-45)=4;
Img(50:end-65,68:end-48)=2; %% Add one more rectangular
Img(68:end-48,50:end-65)=3; %% Add one more rectangular
subplot(121);imagesc(Img);colormap(gray);axis off;axis equal;
L = bwlabel(Img==2);
% imshow(L==1);colormap(gray);hold on; axis off;axis equal;
subplot(122);imagesc(Img);colormap(gray);hold on; axis off;axis equal;
hold on
for label_index=1:max(L(:))
    im = imfill(L==label_index, 'holes');
    [c2,h2] = contour(im,[0 1],'r','LineWidth',2);
end


L = bwlabel(Img==3);
for label_index=1:max(L(:))
    im = imfill(L==label_index, 'holes');
    [c3,h3] = contour(im,[0 1],'g','LineWidth',2);
end

L = bwlabel(Img==4);
for label_index=1:max(L(:))
    im = imfill(L==label_index, 'holes');
    [c3,h3] = contour(im,[0 1],'b','LineWidth',2);
end
hold off
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

ok, more an idea than an answer.

I thought you could change the color of the boundaries instead of using `contour`.

```
figure
Img=ones(128,128);

 %the boundaries of two boxes
Img(20:end-20, 20)=2;
Img(20:end-20, end-20)=2;
Img(20, 20:end-20)=2;
Img(end-20, 20:end-20)=2;

Img(30:end-30, 30)=3;
Img(30:end-30, end-30)=3;
Img(30, 30:end-30)=3;
Img(end-30, 30:end-30)=3;


imagesc(Img);
cm = colormap(gray);

%modify the colormap for the different boundaries
colordata = cm;
colordata(findnearest([1:length(colordata)]/length(colordata), 2/max(max(Img))),:) = [1 0 0];
cm = colormap(colordata);

colordata = cm;
colordata(findnearest([1:length(colordata)]/length(colordata), 3/max(max(Img))),:) = [0 1 0];
colormap(colordata)
```

[image]

If you understand why the red is not at 2 in the colorbar you are done. I couldn't figure it out. Hope this helps somehow..

N.B. I used [`findneareest`](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2838-findnearest-m) to find the colomap entry I wanted to modify.

Comment: Is it possible to draw contour for inside rectangular in my question?

Comment: It does not solve my issue. Do you understand my issue?